# geom_text_repel not working with plotly

Tags: r, plotly

```
**load the data**
 data <-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/school_earnings.csv")


**bubble chart with ggplot**

g<-ggplot(data, aes(x = Women, y = Men, label =School ))+
geom_point(aes(size =gap,alpha=0.5),shape=21, stroke = 0.5,colour = "black")+
geom_text_repel(size = 3,fontface = 'bold', color = 'black',segment.alpha = 0,segment.color = 'grey50' )

**plot output with ggplot**

g
```

[image]

```
**using ggplolty to convert ggplot to plolty**

ggplotly(g)

**plot output with ggplotly**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


But this did not print text of bubbles and give warning

**Warning messages:**
1: We recommend that you use the dev version of ggplot2 with ggplotly()
Install it with: devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')
2: In geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]) :
geom_GeomTextRepel() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
If you'd like to see this geom implemented,
Please open an issue with your example code at

github.com/ropensci/plotly
```

[image]

I am using `ggplot` to render the plot because i didn't found any
 way in plotly to repel the overlapping labels when the number of
 bubbles are more on plot

Comment: What's your question? The warning message tells you that `repel` doesn't work in Plotly, are you asking for some other way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: i want to prevent the labels overlapping when number of bubbles are more on plot

Comment: I have solved the problem using ggrepel with ggplot but i am not able to achieve the same with plolty

Comment: @rajanthind hello, thank you for your question - could you please let me know how you solved the problem using `ggrepel` with `ggplot2`? I am trying to plot a figure with `ggrepel` to show in a shiny app, but the labels just won't show up. I appreciate your feedback. Thank you!